# IVP of $z=xz_x + yz_y +z_xz_y$ with Charpit's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Find the complete integral of $z=px + qy +pq$, where  $p={ \partial  z \over \partial x},q={ \partial  z \over \partial y},$ and initial conditions are $z = y^2 , x=0$.

*My Attempt*:

The given equation is : $f(x,y,z,p,q)=px+qy+pq-z$. $z=y^2 , x=0$ So, [Charpit's auxiliary equations](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/charpits_method_compl_int.pdf) are given by:

$$ds={dp \over 0}={dq \over 0}= {dz \over z+pq}={dx \over x+q}={dy \over y+p}$$

Now, from $$ {dp \over 0}={dq \over 0} $$ we get $p=c_1$, $c_1$ being arbitrary constants. I use the original PDE to get

$$ q={z-c_1x \over y+c_1}$$

Now, I have to use $$dz=pdx+qdy=c_1dx+{z-c_1x \over y+c_1}dy$$ we get $$z(x,y) - c_1x = c_2(y+c_1)$$ Now, I am stuck, because we need to apply the initial conditions, which will never be satisfied by the complete integral

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

$$xz_x+yz_y+z_xz_y-z=0 \tag 1$$
You have correctly found a set of solutions of the form :
$$z(x,y)=c_1x+c_2y+c_1c_2 \tag 2$$
This set of solutions is commonly called a "complete integral". But this is not the general solution of the PDE. They are other solutions than $(2)$.

For example :
$$z(x,y)=-xy$$
$z_x=-y$ and $z_y=-x$

$xz_x+yz_y+z_xz_y-z=x(-y)+y(-x)+(-y)(-x)-(-xy)=0$ which proves that $z=-xy$ is a solution of the PDE.
$$ $$

The solution of the PDE which satisfies the condition $z(0,y)=y^2$ is :
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=y^2+\frac{1}{16}x^2-\frac12 xy} \tag 3$$
$z_x=\frac18 x -\frac12 y$

$z_y=2y -\frac12 x$

$xz_x+yz_y+z_xz_y-z=x(\frac18 x -\frac12 y)+y(2y -\frac12 x)+(\frac18 x -\frac12 y)(2y -\frac12 x)-(y^2+\frac{1}{16}x^2-\frac12 xy)$

After simplification $=0$ which proves that $(3)$ is a solution of the PDE.